# Filed name appearing on same line

Tags: php, mysql

Some code to fetch the field names by connecting it with db:

```
<?php

    @mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error());
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sample");
$storeArray = Array();

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $storeArray = $row['name'];
echo $storeArray;

}
}
?>
```

The above code works just fine but when it runs it gives me `ramuraja`. Here `ramu` and `raja` are seperate fields. But its giving me a joined output.

How can i get the two field value seperately like `ramu` and `raja`.

Comment: You can either `echo "$storeArray \n"` or `echo "$storeArray <br>"` and it should suffice :)

Comment: @MoshMage wow man that did the job

Answer (score 0):

You print / echo the values directly after one another. Using `echo $storeArray.'<br>';` would print a linebreak additionally, thus printing

```
ramu
Raja
```

However, you could also store all the variables in an array, for example with `$storeArray[] = $row['name'];` instead of `$storeArray = $row['name'];`. That would create a new array element, the value being `$row['name']`, while the key is incrementing for every element being added.

After having received all rows that match the query, you could loop through the array and Display the answers.

EDIT: Please check out `mysqli` or `PDO`; those PHP extensions are standard with newer versions and should be used instead of the old (and now deprecated) `mysqli` solution. Don't worry, they can do the same (and much more).

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a for each statement to iterate through the array and echo the field along with a line break

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're declaring `$storeArray` as an array in this line: `$storeArray = Array();`, but later you replace it with a string `$storeArray = $row['name'];`

If you want to use `$storeArray` as an array, change this line:

```
$storeArray = $row['name'];
```

into

```
$storeArray[] = $row['name']; //add element to the array
```

Now loop all the results (remove `echo $storeArray;`)

After you've fetched all the results you kan echo them like:

```
foreach($storeArray as $name){
    echo $name.'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some confusion in code ....
first check ifthere are results:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        ....
    }
}
```

than be more clear about what you wont:

an array :

```
$storeArray = Array();
```

or a string:

```
$storeArray = $row['name'];
```

I would so like this:

```
    $storeArray = Array();
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
               $storeArray[] = $row['name'];
            }
        }

    // array
    print_r($storeArray);

    // string
    echo implode(',', $storeArray);
```